# How to Use application Insights REST API in Visual Studio MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-application-insights

I want to retrieve all the data that is present in my resource on the azure portal. I have found out that there is a REST API for application insights that can help in retrieving the data. What I want is to get the data and generate a grid report on my web page which displays the events related information, that is, date, type, message and all the related information. I haven't worked with REST API's before and what I want as a help is a proper guideline to use this REST API  in my MVC based web project in visual studio. If anyone can help will be a great assistance.

Comment: They seem to have some pretty good documentation on their site found here: https://dev.applicationinsights.io/ and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/

Also, it may be worth looking into RestSharp as a way to easily build requests, send them, and get the response.  There's a bunch of info available for RestSharp online.

Comment: @parameter any link to RestSharp please?

Comment: Here you go :)
http://restsharp.org/
I edited my first comment to include another link to some microsoft docs. There seemed to be more 'How-To's there.

Comment: @parameter thanks...…..let me check and then I will reurn

Comment: @parameter I actually want to fetch data from azure portal's resource with whom my web app is configured and I don't have any experience of working with the REST  API's before.

Comment: @parameter I think RestSharp will not work in this case

Comment: hmm, okay.  Have you seen this link: https://dev.applicationinsights.io/quickstart

This provides a quickstart example on authenticating with and retrieving data from the API.

Comment: @parameter yeah I saw that but things were not cleared to me

Comment: @parameter how do I embed this example I my code?? don't know

Answer (score 27):

You can follow the steps below:

step 1: Get the Application ID and an API key.

Nav to your application insights -> API Access, see the screenshot(Please remember, when the api key is generated, write it down):
[image]

step 2: Understand the API Format, for details, refer to [here](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/Overview/URL-formats):

Here is an example for get requests count in the last 6 hours:

```
https://api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps/your-application-id/metrics/requests/count?timespan=PT6H
```

This part `https://api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps/` do not need to change.

Then input `your-application-id` which you get from last step.

Then you can specify `metrics` or `events` as per your demand.

This part `requests/count`, you can refer to [this](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/Using-the-API/Metrics), screenshot below:
[image]

The last part `?timespan=PT6H`, you can refer to [this](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/reference), screenshot below:
[image]

step 3: Write your code to call this api, like below:

```
public class Test
{
 private const string URL_requests = "https://api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps/your-application-id/metrics/requests/count?timespan=PT6H";

 public string GetRequestsCount()
        {
            // in step 1, you get this api key
            string apikey = "flk2bqn1ydur57p7pa74yc3aazhbzf52xbyxthef";

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-api-key", apikey);
            var req = string.Format(URL_requests);
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(req).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                // you can get the request count here
                return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            }
            else
            {
                return response.ReasonPhrase;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: So sad to see such a great answer - and not a single upvote (before now) and not even an accepted answer.

Comment: It would appear that the above URL is no longer available (as of 2023).  This alternative seems to work though: https://dc.services.visualstudio.com/v2/track.  Source: https://github.com/MohanGsk/ApplicationInsights-Home/blob/master/EndpointSpecs/ENDPOINT-PROTOCOL.md